# Apache POI цифровая подпись

Tags: java, signature, poi

Пытаюсь подписать word документ с помощью цифровой подписи используя Apache POI. Есть JKS хранилище с парой открытый-закрытый ключ. Вытаскиваю ключ из хранилища и пытаюсь подписать с помощью следующего кода:

```
public void sign() throws Exception {

  char password[] = "qwe".toCharArray();
  File file = new File("C:/testkeystore.pfx");
  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  keystore.load(fis, password);
  fis.close();

  String alias = "pupkinv"; 
  Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password);
  X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate)keystore.getCertificate(alias);
  SignatureConfig signatureConfig = new SignatureConfig();
  signatureConfig.setKey((PrivateKey)key);

  signatureConfig.setExecutionTime(cal.getTime());
  signatureConfig.setDigestAlgo(HashAlgorithm.sha256);


  signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new EnvelopedSignatureFacet());
  signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new KeyInfoSignatureFacet());

  signatureConfig.setSigningCertificateChain(Collections.singletonList(x509));
  OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open("C:/123.docx", PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
  signatureConfig.setOpcPackage(pkg);

  SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
  si.setSignatureConfig(signatureConfig);
  si.confirmSignature();


  for (SignaturePart sp : si.getSignatureParts()) {
    assert sp.validate();
  }
  assert si.verifySignature();

  pkg.close();
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3/x2000/x09/xmldsig/SignatureDocument$Factory
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo.writeDocument(SignatureInfo.java:653)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo.postSign(SignatureInfo.java:610)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureInfo.confirmSignature(SignatureInfo.java:341)
at test.Signer.pizda(Signer.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3.x2000.x09.xmldsig.SignatureDocument$Factory
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1501)
    ... 61 more

По трасирровке останавливается на si.confirmSignature(); Что я делают не так?

Comment: `at test.Signer.pizda(Signer.java:86)` - проблема явно в вашей pizd'e)

Comment: это и есть public void sign() throws Exception

Comment: Вы понимаете что написано в первой строке приведённой вами "ошибке"? Не найден указанный класс. Похоже у вас каких-то библиотек не хватает.

Comment: Да, не хватало ooxml-security.